# PowerShell obtención de token mediante secret y key

Tags: javascript, json, api, fetch, tokens

Tengo una consulta sobre como conseguir el token con JS(usando fetch) de la manera en que lo hago desde el siguiente código en powershell;(lo necesito pasar a un js para trabajarlo con html y sql al consumirla) en el siguiente codigo obtengo el token mediante 2 valores la secretkey y la key, con estos valores ya obtengo el token necesario para hacer peticiones en la api

```
$base64AuthInfo
$baseURL="https://rutabase de la api/"

#Trust HTTPS
#from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696944/powershell-v3-invoke-webrequest-https-error
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
try{
add-type @"

    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy{
         public bool CheckValidationResult(
             ServicePoint srvPoint,X509Certificate certificate,
             WebRequest request,int certificateProblem) {
             return true;
             }
            }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
} catch{}



#HTTP Access Token
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $base64AuthInfo")
$headers.Add("Host", "localhost")
$headers.Add("User-Agent", "powershell")
$headers.Add("Accept", "/")
$headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "powershell")
$body = "grant_type=client_credentials"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod "$baseURL/learn/api/public/v1/oauth2/token" -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
$access_token = $response.access_token
Write-Host $access_token -Fore "Yellow"

#HTTP Query Courses
$headers=New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $access_token")
$response = Invoke-RestMethod "$baseURL/learn/api/public"-Headers $headers
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```